# c# base serializer type

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am having problems with a user control that uses a third party control (I'm not sure if that is part of the question). I read various ways of resolving the fact that the VS designer has problems visualizing some user controls, but the solution that made the most sense to me was to add DesignerSerializer attribute.

```
[DesignerSerializer("MyControls.BaseControlCodeDomSerializer", typeof(CodeDomSerializer))]

public partial class PagesControl : UserControl
```

However when I added the code below it throws an error saying the typeof variable (i.e. CodeDomSerializer) could not be found. How can a base windows type NOT BE FOUND. I get no recommendation from ReSharper on some library that needs to added to resolve this.

Comment: I'm assuming you have the `System.Design` dll in your references, yes?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.serialization.codedomserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeDomSerializer type was defined in assembly System.Design.dll. Try adding the reference.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.serialization.codedomserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No I did not have System.Design.dll reference added to project. Thanks for the answer. That took care of the syntax error.